# Why do I get 'uninitialized constant' in Active Admin when I create a new resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have set up Rails active admin and the interface loads up just fine for me here is my setup in my Gemfile:

```
# Use all the things Active Admin needs ================== 
gem 'devise',              github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'responders',          github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'

gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.2"
```

I can go to /admin and it loads up the interface just fine.

The only issue I have is when I say do command:

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Pages
```

It generates the resource in my /app/admin/pages.rb but when I reload the page I get the error.

**The complete error message:**

```
NameError
uninitialized constant Pages

Extracted source (around line #1):
1 ActiveAdmin.register Pages do
2
3 end

Rails.root: /Freelance/Current Projects/Birch/forge

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/admin/pages.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /Freelance/Current Projects/Birch/forge/config/routes.rb
   /Freelance/Current Projects/Birch/forge/app/admin/pages.rb
```

Has anyone got a clue as to why that would happen? I have done nothing to break it or anything so not sure what it could be.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Is you model called Page or Pages?

Comment: its called Pages, I tried all sorts of different resource names and I still got the same error, so its not just pages

Comment: Josh forgot to say, I added the whole error message above

Comment: Models with plural names can turn into huge PITAs

Comment: okay but even without the 's' on Pages I still get the error

Comment: The resource name in AA must match the name of your model (under app/model, AA won't create this for you) exactly.

Comment: But even when I create using `rails generate model Pages` I get the same error in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generated your resource, you used the plural form. You should have run it with the singular name of the model. By default, the register will look for the class passed in to the `ActiveAdmin.register` method. To fix this, assuming you have a model called `Page`, simply remove the `s` ad the end of `Pages` in the top of your admin file.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Page do
end
```

The general convention is for the admin files to be named in the singular.